# Join string with different delimiters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to join a string, but with 2 different delimiter symbols in even and odd situations.

I have this list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I need to join it like this:

```
1 || 2 || \n 3 ||  4 || \n 5 || 6 || \n 7 ||  8 || \n 9
```

So after every two elements an extra newline is added.

Comment: Please explain the pattern behind the delimiters and show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? How far did you get?

Comment: Please don't keep swapping out the expected output. Could you not have determined this up front?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join every two elements, then join the results:

```
' || \n '.join([' || '.join([str(v) for v in l[i:i + 2]]) for i in range(len(l))])
```

Or broken down into two expressions:

```
paired = [' || '.join([str(v) for v in l[i:i + 2]]) for i in range(len(l))]
final = ' || \n '.join(paired)
```

The latter works better with your altered expected output.

Demo:

```
>>> ' || \n '.join([' || '.join([str(v) for v in l[i:i + 2]]) for i in range(len(l))])
'1 || 2 || \n 2 || 3 || \n 3 || 4 || \n 4 || 5 || \n 5 || 6 || \n 6 || 7 || \n 7 || 8 || \n 8 || 9 || \n 9'
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It's what i'm need. But i'm need to practice in generators to write this self:)

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
' || '.join(str(n) if n % 2 else '\n ' + str(n) for n in l)
```

Comment: That won't work if the inputs are not consecutive numbers.

Comment: Also, the expected output was changed, you'd have to swap your condition or your expressions, at which point you'll get a stray `\n` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I made this small script:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ret=""

for i in l:
    ret=ret + str(i);
    if i != 9:
        ret = ret + " || ";
    if i % 2 == 0:
        ret = ret + "\n ";
ret
```

```

Comment: This is a more dynamic version, with comments:

    l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    ret=""
    
    for i in l:
        ret=ret + str(i);
        # Add double pipe except for the last occurence
        if i != l[-1]:
            ret = ret + " || ";
        # Every 2 values, go to newline
        if i % 2 == 0:
            ret = ret + "\n ";
    ret

Answer (score 0):

This is a more dynamic version, with comments:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ret=""

for i in l:
    ret=ret + str(i);
    # Add double pipe except for the last occurence
    if i != l[-1]:
        ret = ret + " || ";
    # Every 2 values, go to newline
    if i % 2 == 0:
        ret = ret + "\n ";
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hey guys am just a beginner in python but i tried to come up with a code for that question above i hope it is helpful somehow.
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lst = []
lst_odd = []
delimeter1 = '| |'
delimeter2 = "/n"
count = 0
for num in l:
    if count == 0:
        x = str(num)
        lst.append(x)
        count += 1
    else:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            y = str(num)
            lst.append(y)
        else:
            z = str(num)
            lst_odd.append((delimeter2+z))
    if count == 2:
            break
main = [lst[0],lst[1],lst_odd[0],lst[2],lst_odd[1],lst[3],lst_odd[2],lst[4],lst_odd[3]]
s = delimeter1.join(main)
print(s)
```

Comment: still had issues with that "\n" delimiter as it was creating space.so i decided to first change it and see if the code would progress